# Alias inside function

Tags: bash, sh, alias

```sh
bash -c 'shopt -s expand_aliases

a() {
    alias myfunc="echo myfunc"
}

main() {
    a
    myfunc
}

main'
```

`a` function is used to alias some commands, which are used in `main` function.

Output:

```
environment: line 8: myfunc: command not found
```

Comment: interesting question. If you take `a` and `myfunc` out of main and run them at the "global" level, no error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected behavior, explained in [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html) as follows:

> Aliases are expanded when a function definition is **read**, not when the function is **executed**, because a function definition is itself a command.

In this case that means `myfunc` in `main` is not going to be expanded to `echo myfunc` unless your script **calls** `a` to define it above the definition of `main`.

The shell does not execute commands inside a function definition until that function is called. So, defining `a` above `main` doesn't make any difference; `myfunc` isn't defined until `a` is called.

Compare these two:

```
$ bash -O expand_aliases -c '
foo() { bar; }
alias bar=uname
foo'
environment: line 1: bar: command not found
```

```
$ bash -O expand_aliases -c '
alias bar=uname
foo() { bar; }
foo'
Linux
```

The workaround is to avoid using aliases in shell scripts. Functions are way better.